# atoi y 9223372036854775808 (2^63)

Tags: c

Probando atoi me he dado cuenta de que a partir de 2^63 devuelve 0 si el numero que debiera devolver es negativo, y -1 si el numero que debiera devolver es positivo, alguien tiene idea de porque?

Answer (score 1):

La finalidad de la función `int atoi (const char * str)` es convertir una cadena representando un entero a un entero. Así como está documentado [aquí](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/), si la cifra convertida queda fuera del rango que un `int` puede representar (`LONG_MIN` y `LONG_MAX` definitos en `limits.h`) entonces el comportamiento es indefinido.

Dependerá entonces del compilador que estés usando para saber el porqué del comportamiento observado.

Comment: Entiendo las peculiaridades de cada compilador, aun asi cuando sobrepasamos LONG_MAX (2^31 -1) esto hace overflow y empieza por el minimo int, vamos es como un bucle, y este bucle se repite si seguimos poniendo numero mas grandes y mas grandes hasta que llegamos al numero al numero en cuestion (2^63) a partir del cual los resultados son o bien 0 o bien -1, y esto no me parece un comportamiento indefinido mas bien parece hecho adrede.

Comment: indefinido != aleatorio. Se refiere a que el comportamiento en cuestión no se encuentra definido en alguna especificación y se le da entonces la libertad al proveedor de la librería de definir el comportamiento en ese caso.